# Handling delete in SCD TYPE_2 By using Informatica Power Centre

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are trying to implement SCD type_2 using Informatica on the oracle 12C environment, the insert and update logic along with start and end date is working as per requirements, Can anyone please let me know how the delete logic can be implemented under the same? . how can we capture the source deleted records in SCD type_2?

Comment: join source with target, if you dint find a match fir a target riw flag it as delete and use `dd_delete`

Comment: Are you asking how to identify deleted records in your Oracle source system or are you asking how to process this deletion information once you have received it from Oracle? Are you using a CDC connector?

Comment: @NickW Yes, you are exactly correct, I would like to know how to identify and process the deleted information once it is received from the source. The current logic which we are using for SCD type_2 is using the Start date and end date along with the Flag column. with the help of look upon the target table.

Answer (score 0):

The standard logic for processing SCD2 deletions is to:

1. Look up the current dimension record from the source deletion record
2. On the retrieved dimension record, set the SCD end date to the deletion date and the current flag to false